# Laravel 5: order by subtraction in eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to perform this query using Eloquent

```
select * from `reviews` order by `up_vote` - `down_vote` desc
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$top_reviews = $productDetails->reviews()->orderBy('up_vote - down_vote','DESC')->get();
```

But I am getting `Unknown column 'up_vote - down_vote'`. Is it possible to do this without using `DB` ?
**Update:** I have found a method `orderByRaw` which working fine. See [Laravel API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw). 
Now I am doing like this:

```
$productDetails->reviews()->orderByRaw('`up_vote` - `down_vote` DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Try `'up_vote' - 'down_vote'`

Comment: Did you find how to do it ? I'm stuck with the same problem here :(

Comment: Did you check my update on the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think, You should do

```
$reviews->select('*', '(up_vote - down_vote) AS profit')
    ->orderBy('profit','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to avoid DB as I already mentioned in question. I am doing like this: $product_detail->reviews() from view.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal, You can actually use select() method without using DB

Comment: Yea. missed it. But this is my full code:

`$productDetails = Product::where(['typeID' => $typeID, 'languageID' => $this->languageID])->first();
$top_reviews = $productDetails->reviews()
                                        ->where(['status' => 'Y', 'languageID' => Session::get('languageID')])
                                        ->orderBy('up_vote - down_vote','DESC')
                                       ->take(10)->get();`
Is it possible to do the same?

Comment: Yes, You can write $productDetails->reviews()->->select('*', '(up_vote - down_vote) AS profit')->.....->where()->.....->orderBy('profit','DESC')->get();

Comment: It producing up_vote` as `down_vote.. hence not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
$top_reviews = $reviews()->orderBy('up_vote', '-', 'down_vote','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: No its not working. Its causing syntax error, unexpected ''-''

Comment: check above method , i missed comma.

Comment: No it is not work eliminating other parameters except first parameter. Though I have found `orderByRaw($sql, $bindings = [])` method in Query/Builder.php. Its working fine.